# Tuning parameters in caret error despite assigning grids and as.factor

Tags: machine-learning, r-caret

Any help appreciated.  Been at this for weeks. :(

```
install.packages("klaR", dependencies=TRUE) 
library(klaR)
install.packages("caret", dependencies=TRUE)
library(caret)
install.packages("e1071", dependencies=TRUE)
library(e1071)
install.packages("gmodels", dependencies=TRUE)
library(gmodels)
install.packages("gbm", dependencies=TRUE)
library(gbm)
install.packages("foreach", dependencies=TRUE)
library(foreach)
```

Load Grading Data

```
grading <- read.csv("~/PA_DataFinal/GradingData160315.csv")
```

create stratified sample @ 1%

```
dfstrat <- stratified(grading, "FailPass", .01)
save(dfstrat, file =      "c:/Users/gillisn/Documents/PA_DataFinal/RResults/GradingRResults/iteration 1/dfstrat.rda")
```

split data into train and test @75:25.  FailPass is the responseVble

```
set.seed(1)
inTrainingSet <- createDataPartition(dfstrat$FailPass, p = .75, list =     FALSE)
trainSet <- dfstrat[inTrainingSet,]
testSet <- dfstrat[-inTrainingSet, ]
```

set predictors and labels
There are 48 labels and its the last one that want to train on.
Take all the predictors 1-47
x,y is training data

```
x <- trainSet[,-48]
y <- as.factor(trainSet$FailPass)
```

i,j is test data

```
i <- testSet[,-48,]
j <- as.factor(testSet$FailPass)
```

Set Training control parameters
Bootstrapping itself around in 25 times.

```
bootControl <- trainControl(number = 25)
```

The grid is for the decision tree

```
gbmGrid <- expand.grid(.interaction.depth = (1:5) * 2, .n.trees = (1:10)*25, .shrinkage = .1)
nbGrid <- expand.grid(.fL=0, .usekernel=FALSE)
svmGrid >- expandGrid(.sigma=, .c=)
set.seed(2)
```

Train the models
naive bayes

```
nbFit <- train(x,y,method='nb',tuneGrid="nbGrid")
```

svm

```
svmFit <- train(x, y,method = "svmRadial", tuneLength = 10,trControl =    bootControl, scaled = FALSE)
```

gbm

```
gbmFit <- train(x, y,method = "gbm", trControl = bootControl, verbose = FALSE, bag.fraction = 0.5, tuneGrid = gbmGrid)
```

predict the models on training data

```
models <- list(svm = svmFit, nb = nbFit, gbm = gbmFit)
predict(models)
```

Comment: Have a seperate function to do Stratified Random Sample. just didnt include.

Comment: And what's the error?